# Best method to upload and retrieve files from/to server from/to Android (client side) - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, web-services, xamarin, server

I have a web service (`WCF`) that gets data from the SQL Server. Is using web service more efficient than directly interacting from Android application to the server (where the folder of the files will be uploaded and retrieved). There are parts of my app which needs to get data from SQL Server database but this one doesn't need it, just for accessing that particular folder in the server.

Is there a tutorial in Xamarin which would guide me how to do it? The file types include `PNG`, `JPEG`, `EXCEL`, `PPT`, and `PDF`. I found this but is in `iOS` platform, [Download a File](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_a_file/). This one using web service, [image uploading from android application to server using c# web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164353/image-uploading-from-android-application-to-server-using-c-sharp-web-service) and this using async, [download and view a PDF file](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35402/download-and-view-a-pdf-file).

Am I correct that before uploading it to server, it'll need to be converted to byte array? And for viewing the files from the server to Android app, is there a way to automatically display (if there is an image) it to the app and if it's `EXCEL`, `PPT`, and `PDF`, will show up as a link on the app and when click will ask the user to find an app to view the following file type.

I am absolutely new to this so I'd greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Could always transfer files using FTP ?

Comment: @Doomsknight I honestly do not know but is that possible for interacting between server and android app?

Comment: It depends how you want to interact. If its just to put files on the server and get files off of it then FTP is better. Using a web service is probably better if you wish to process some data with the file transfer. An FTP example, I transfer the database using FTP from the android to the server, then get the android to send an email out using SMTP that some files have been uploaded, and the path to them.

Comment: @Doomsknight The server is only accessible through HTTP so I guess it won't work using FTP.

Comment: [this might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778910/file-streaming-from-android-to-wcf) . The other thing is to look at something like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), although it doesnt support file transfer, i think there are examples of how to implement it

Comment: @doomsknight Thanks! I'll look into it.